# how that GL(V) is a subset of Sym(V)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

$\operatorname{Sym}(X)$ is the group of all bijective maps from $X$ to itself and

$$
\operatorname{GL}(V)=\{f: V \rightarrow V | \text{ f is bijective and linear}\}.
$$

How do I show that $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Sym}(V)$?

I get the point that $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is a subset of $\operatorname{Sym}(V)$ if $f$ in $\operatorname{GL}(V) $ is not linear. But when its linear I have to show in someway that $\operatorname{GL}(V)$ is still a subset.

Comment: You wrote it down in your definition of $GL(V)$.  There is an "and" in there.

Comment: But if GL(V) is a subset of Sym(V), does that not need that Sym(V) is linear?

Comment: What does it mean to be a subset?  The set of dogs is a subset of the set of mammals, but that doesn't mean that horses are dogs.

Answer (score 2):

If $f \in GL(V)$, then $f:V \to V$ is linear and bijective. Since $f$ is bijective, we have that $f \in Sym(V).$ This shows that $GL(V) \subset Sym(V).$